# What is the BizTalk SqmUploader?, and what does it do?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

What is the BizTalk SqmUploader.exe?, which lives in \CEIP\

I can see it in TaskManager, and if I restart my host instance, I can see a number of ...

```
Error in uploading files: HTTP Code : 0
```

and

```
SqlTraceSoruce [sic] Information : 2
```

in my `DbgView` window.

Done a search, but nothing coming up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of the Customer Experience Improvement Program which was introduced in BizTalk Server 2010.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee920495.aspx

It is mandatory during Beta programs but optional in the released product.

You control it in BizTalk Server Configuration under Help -> Customer Feedback Options.

Comment: Excellent, that stopped at least those messages